# compare string and objectId in lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I foundout that there is no option to compare these two .If there is any alternate please tell me.

As you see i have two collection event and eventuser i want list of user from eventuser on the basis 
     of event name in event collection.

But i have userId in string format then how to compare userId column 
     in event with _id column in eventuser collection.
        Event collection

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b5867500be60f139e67c908"), 
"userId" : "5b58674e0be60f139e67cfea", 
"name" : "Add to Cart", 

},
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b5867500be60f139e67c090"), 
"userId" : "5b58674e0be60f139e67cfea", 
"name" : "Searched", 

},
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b5867500be60f139e67c098"), 
"userId" : "5b58674e0be60f139e67cacd", 
"name" : "Add to Cart", 

}


 EventUser Collection

{
"_id":ObjectId("5b58674e0be60f139e67cfea"),
 "name":"jogendra"
},
{
"_id":ObjectId("5b58674e0be60f139e67cfcv"),`
 "name":"jogendra singh"
}




 mmy query- it return users array as empty list
 db.getCollection("event").aggregate([
 {$match:{"name":"Add to Cart"}},
  {$lookup:{
 from:"eventuser",
 localField:"userId",
 foreignFiled:"_id",
 as:"users"
 }}
  ]);
```

Comment: If you have mongodb 4.0 then you can convert `userId` from string to ObjectId with [`$toObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/)

Answer (score 4):

In $lookup [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)  you can't match with string --> _id or _id --> string

Possible case is _id --> _id or string --> string

So you need change your data like this

```
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("5b5867500be60f139e67c908"), 
 "userId" : ObjectId("5b58674e0be60f139e67cfea"), 
 "name" : "Add to Cart", 

},
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("5b5867500be60f139e67c090"), 
 "userId" : ObjectId("5b58674e0be60f139e67cfea"), 
 "name" : "Searched", 

},
{ 
 "_id" : ObjectId("5b5867500be60f139e67c098"), 
 "userId" : ObjectId("5b58674e0be60f139e67cacd"), 
 "name" : "Add to Cart", 

}
```

otherwise, you need to upgrade your MongoDB version 4 and you can use $toObjectId  [$toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $match: { "name": "Add to Cart" } },
{
    $addFields: {
        convertedId: { $toObjectId: "$userId" }
    }
},
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "from_collection",
        "localField": "convertedId",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "data"
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: Thanks Senthur i found an another solution                                                 
       {$project:{convertedUserId:{$convert:{
            input:"$userId", 
            to:"objectId", 
            onError:"Cannot $convert to objectId"
}}}}

Comment: Yes, $convert can convert the string to ObjectId anyway it supports MongoDB latest version only.